# How Can I join Multiple database SQL query in POWERBI

Tags: c#, sql-server, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

When I get data from SQL Server ,

It asks me database(optional) but I cant skip it.

example query below

```
select 
 *
from example1.dbo.table1  CP 
inner join example2.dbo.table2 CC on CC.exampleId=CP.Id
inner join example3.dbo.table3 CT on CC.Id=CT.exampleId
where B.Id='" & Id & "' and CP.Id in
(
select xId from example1.dbo.table1 
where Id='" & Id & "'
)
```

So I need to join 3 tables from 3 database.
BTW I know server and I have admin account.
With a single admin account I can connect that 3 database.

I tried import mode,
It asks me database.
When I write one of that 3 database name into that place,

```
Details: "Microsoft SQL: The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context.
```

How can I solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can find additional details on that specific error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309922/the-target-principal-name-is-incorrect-cannot-generate-sspi-context)

When you connect to the SQL Database make sure you are selecting the correct authentication mechanism. Windows is for your network login and password. Database is for a SQL username and password and Microsoft account is for an Azure AD account (e.g. what you would use to log in to Exchange Online or Office 365).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used `OLE DB` mode Instead of  `SQL Server - Import` to solve the problem.