# Only on one server: "SQL Server Network Interfaces: The target principal name is incorrect."

Tags: sql-server-2019, spn

(EDIT: I think this is sufficiently different from
[The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309922/the-target-principal-name-is-incorrect-cannot-generate-sspi-context) to not be a duplicate.)

We've got two servers (`SQL01` and `SQL02`) in the same domain.  SQL Server on SQL02 can connect to SQL Server on SQL01, but not vice versa.  On each node, `ping -a` and `telnet mumble 1433` work fine.  I've tried all combinations of non- and fully-qualified server names, with and without port number.

The only difference is that SPN on node 2 has two extra entries (circled in red).  Should I delete them from node 2, or add similar records to node 1?

Node 1:

```
C:\Users\mumble>hostname
EW0VPNYWSQL01

C:\Users\mumble> sqlcmd -E -S EW0VPNYWSQL02.NYEZPCI.LOCAL,1433
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : SQL Server Network Interfaces: The target principal name is incorrect.
.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Cannot generate SSPI context.
```

Node 2:

```
C:\Users\mumble>hostname
EW0VPNYWSQL02

C:\Users\mumble>sqlcmd -E -S EW0VPNYWSQL01.NYEZPCI.LOCAL,1433
1
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do the following steps:

- Stop SQL Server service + SQL Agent on SQL02
- Delete "MSSQLsvc" SPN's manually
- Run:

  ```
  setspn -d MSSQLSvc/EW0VPNYWSQL02.NYEZPCI.com:1433 NYEZPCI\EW0VPNYWSQL02
  ```
- Run:

  ```
  setspn -d MSSQLSvc/EW0VPNYWSQL02.NYEZPCI.com NYEZPCI\EW0VPNYWSQL02
  ```
- Start SQL Server service + SQL Agent on SQL02

I guess that at one time, the SQL Server service has been started with `NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER`, before changing it to a domain service account