# Cannot access msmdpump.dll by server name, but can by IP

Tags: sql-server, http, ssas, kerberos, spn

## Summary

We are working to enable http(s) connectivity to our SSAS cubes. I have followed the Microsoft Documentation ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0?view=asallproducts-allversions&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver15)) to set up the msmdpump files and can successfully access them via SSMS and Excel by IP, but when the server name is entered a "401 Unauthorized - The target principal name is incorrect" error is returned. What could be causing this failure?

## Details

Connecting Via SSMS:

This works: `http://0.0.0.0/olap/msmdpump.dll` (actual IP address not shown)

This **does not** work: `http://myservername.mydomain.com/olap/msmdpump.dll` (actual server name not shown)

Error Message:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server    
------------------------------    
Cannot connect to http://myservername.mydomain.com/olap/msmdpump.dll.    
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:    
The connection either timed out or was lost. (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient)    
------------------------------    
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. (System)    
------------------------------    
The target principal name is incorrect (System)
```

I placed a very simple HTML file in the OLAP directory and I can successfully browse to it via a web browser.

Running this on the command line `SetSPN -1 domain\myserviceaccount` returns the following entries (actual values obscured):

```
MSSQLSvc/myservername.mydomain.com
MSSQLSvc/myservername.mydomain.com:1234
MSOLAPSvc.3/myservername
MSOLAPSvc.3/myservername.mydomain.com
http/myservername
http/myservername.mydomain.com
```

We are using Windows Authentication.

## Update

If we remove the HTTP SPN entries, then it works again however to allow external access they are necessary.

Attempting to digest this MS Link: [SPN registration for an Analysis Services instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/analysis-services/instances/spn-registration-for-an-analysis-services-instance?view=asallproducts-allversions#bkmk_spnHTTP)

Comment: As per your link, _Windows authentication is considered the most secure, and leverages existing infrastructure for networks that use Active Directory. To use Windows authentication effectively, all browsers, client applications, and server applications must support it. This is the most secure and recommended mode, but it requires that IIS be able to access a Windows domain controller that can authenticate the identity of the user requesting a connection._ Have you checked trust relationships yet with [`Test-ComputerSecureChannel -Verbose`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32387085/390122)?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I just checked and it seems ok. `VERBOSE: The secure channel between the local computer and the domain mydomain.com is in good condition.` Also, this seems to be a different error than the `cannot generate sspi context`